# How can i redirect my magento page with urlkey

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, controllers, url-rewrite, redirect

How can i redirect my magento page with urlkey in my controller 
i just made custom form that save data in database

after submit data i want to redirect to same page where that data sent[image]

but want url like

**localhost/b/index.php/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html/**

Comment: Please explain the question neatly what you really needed and also if possible show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by "URL Rewrite Management"

Catalog->URL Rewrite Management-> Click "Add URL Rewrite" button Then Select "For Category" -> Select a category you want to rewrite to product page.

[image]

Then enter your product url in 4th field "Request Path". here hoodies.html is my product URL: http://localhost.com/magento/hoodies.html and then Select "redirect permanent 301" from the list "Redirect".

[image]